# InstantiationException when Instantiate generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

I have been trying to get this to work for a while and I have searched high and low for answers (including here). But I can't figure it out.

So here the code (a bit minimized):

```
public class Event<T> {
    public MessageType msgType;
    public int layer;
    public int gameObjectId;
    public String name;
    public float value;
    public int senderId;
    public T ext;

    public Event(Class<T> classType) {
        if(classType != null) {
            try {
                ext = classType.newInstance();  //this is the failing line
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        msgType = MessageType.NONE;
        layer = TypeHandler.lAll;
        gameObjectId = -1;
        name = null;
        value = -1;
    }
}

public class DataExtension {
    public float[] values;
    public String[] string;
    public Object[] objects;
    public boolean[] boolens;
}
```

This is the problem:

```
Event<DataExtension> mSelectionEvent;

mSelectionEvent = new Event<DataExtension>(DataExtension.class, MessageType.SELECTED);
```

This give me the following exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: se.plainentertainment.bagl.v2.core.Event$DataExtension
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at se.plainentertainment.bagl.v2.core.Event.<init>(Event.java:85)
    at se.plainentertainment.bagl.v2.core.SelectionHandler.<init>(SelectionHandler.java:46)...
```

So, the class that I'm trying to instantiate should meet all the requirements, right? It has a default constructor and it's not abstract in any way. Why do I get this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tried to run this code with some small modifications and I don't get any problems. The modification are: 1. Create two class files (java files) one for Event and one for DataExtension; 2. Comment out the references to the enums, you didn't provide source for them; 3. Create a main class to test. This works fine.

Comment: What? Okay, so the only difference is that my DataExtension is defined inside of the event class... that must be the problem, let me check.

Comment: Well, that was how I read your code. The code you posted will not compile. And I think the DataExtension should be defined outside the Event.

Comment: It worked now, thanks! :)

This thing with class definitions inside of another class has given me trouble before. I can't really figure out when to use them. I mean in this case I placed the extension class there because it was only created to be used with the Event class. So just for convenience. But that is a bad reason i guess?

Comment: That is a bad reason. Creating inner classes in Java is a convenience used when grouping closely linked functionality that should not leak. In other words a way to structure a class without leaking functionality into the package. I recommend not using it if at all possible since the design usually is muddled by it.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that... There is going to be a lot of class files :/

Comment: Java system generally contains a lot of files. It's how Java is structured, compared to languages like Python, Groovy or Scala. Use packages and sensible names to keep track of what is were and you will find that this is less of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event$DataExtension
```

This is an inner class.  Is it static?  I'm going to go with a hunch and say no.  Which means it contains a reference to the containing Event (implicitly), which means you likely can't instantiate it via newInstance.

Try setting it to be a static inner class, or move it out of the class it if it doesn't need to be tied to the event object.

Comment: I moved out or the Event class, that was the problem just as Tomas Malmsten pointed out. Thanks again!